# Vue JS: Conditional logic inside v-on:keyup.enter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can the "activate" method call be made conditionally when the user presses the enter key?

I would have expected the following to work but it does not:

```
<input type="text" v-model="code" v-on:keyup.enter="code.match(/^\d{6}$/) ? activate : null">

methods: {
    activate() {
        ...
    },
```

Comment: What do you want your function to do when the keyup event is called?

Comment: @HumayonZafar call the "activate" method

Comment: Simple try using this:

<input type="text" v-model="code"  v-on:keyup.enter="activate">

methods: {
    activate() {
        console.log('key pressed');
    },

Comment: @HumayonZafar - Thanks, v-on:keyup.enter="activate" works fine. I am trying to add a conditional inside v-on:keyup.enter to only call the "activate" method if the condition is true as shown in the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this approach instead. Move the logic to another method and call the activated from that method if it meets your criteria to call activate.

```
    <input type="text" v-model="code" v-on:keyup.enter="keyPressed">
    
    methods: {
        keyPressed() {
            if(this.code.match(/^\d{6}$/)){
               activate() 
            }
        },
        activate() {
          ...
         }
    }
```